# ¿Cómo calcular el recuento de datos faltantes para columnas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Sigo intentando llevar mi conocimiento del análisis de datos al límite.

Tengo quatros marco de datos de un archivo csv que descargué [aquí](https://www.lendingclub.com/info/download-data.action) (préstamos bancarios del año 2018. Se dividen en cuatro trimestres). Los descargué de esta manera:

```
data_Q1 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q1.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q2 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q3 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
data_Q4 = pd.read_csv("LoanStats_2018Q2.csv", skiprows=1, skipfooter=2, engine='python')

frames = [data_Q1,data_Q2,data_Q3,data_Q4]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

¿Cómo encontrar el número de datos faltantes en una columna? Y, por lo tanto, ¿Cómo calcular el recuento de datos faltantes para columnas?

Aqui es un extracto de `result` :

```
    id  member_id   loan_amnt   funded_amnt funded_amnt_inv term    int_rate    installment grade   sub_grade   ... orig_projected_additional_accrued_interest  hardship_payoff_balance_amount  hardship_last_payment_amount    debt_settlement_flag    debt_settlement_flag_date   settlement_status   settlement_date settlement_amount   settlement_percentage   settlement_term
0   NaN NaN 35000   35000   35000.0 60 months   13.58%  806.79  C   C2  ... NaN NaN NaN N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN 24000   24000   24000.0 36 months   21.85%  914.71  D   D5  ... NaN NaN NaN N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN 2500    2500    2500.0  36 months   6.71%   76.87   A   A3  ... NaN NaN NaN N   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a contar el número de filas en una columna dada  con valores NaN?

Comment: @FJSevilla La pregunta que me hicieron es, en inglés, _"How may columns contain missing data? What is the count of missing data for each of this column?"_ que traducé en _¿Cómo pueden las columnas contener datos faltantes? ¿Cuál es el recuento de datos faltantes para cada una de esta columna?_ pienso que hay una error (es columnas y no columna). Entonces piense que se trata de contar los elementos de NaN para cada columna.

Comment: Si... Yo le encontraría más sentido si fuera "How ma**n**y columns contain missing data? What is the count of missing data for each of **these columns**?, es decir "¿Cuántas columnas contienen datos faltantes? ¿Cuál es el recuento de datos faltantes para cada una de estas columnas?"

Comment: @FJSevilla Si ! Así lo entiendo yo también.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos crear una máscara boleana que identifique los valores nulos existentes en el DataFrame con `pandas.DataFrame.isna` o `pandas.DataFrame.isnull` (alias del anterior).

Hecho esto podemos aplicar `pandas.DataFrame.sum` para obtener una serie con los nombres de las columnas como índice y la suma de valores nulos que hay en cada una.

Si queremos tener en cuenta solo aquellas columnas que tienen al menos un valor nulo, podemos aplicar otro filtro boleano sobre la serie.

Un ejemplo con un DataFrame simplificado:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = io.StringIO(
"""
col1,col2,col3,col4
,,19,
2,8,11,
5,13,4,
,8,7,2
"""
)

result = pd.read_csv(data)
miss_values_count = result.isnull().sum(min_count=1)
miss_values_count = miss_values_count[miss_values_count != 0]
```

> ```
> >>> result
>
>    col1  col2  col3  col4
> 0   NaN   NaN    19   NaN
> 1   2.0   8.0    11   NaN
> 2   5.0  13.0     4   NaN
> 3   NaN   8.0     7   2.0
>
> >>> miss_values_count
>
> col1    2
> col2    1
> col4    3
> dtype: int64
> ```

Con una salida más legible:

```
miss_values_count = result.isnull().sum(min_count=1)
miss_values_count = miss_values_count[miss_values_count != 0]

print(f"Número de columnas con datos faltantes: {miss_values_count.shape[0]}")
if miss_values_count.shape[0]:
    print("Recuento de valores nulos por columna: ")
    for name, miss_vals in miss_values_count.items():
        p = miss_vals > 1
        print(f"  - A la columna '{name}' le falta{'n' if p else ''} "
              f"{miss_vals} dato{'s' if p else ''}.")
```

> ```
> Número de columnas con datos faltantes: 3
> Recuento de valores nulos por columna: 
>   - A la columna 'col1' le faltan 2 datos.
>   - A la columna 'col2' le falta 1 dato.
>   - A la columna 'col4' le faltan 3 datos.
> ```